# Build Number throwing error after upgrading to Flutter 3.7.3

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-upgrade, pubspec.yaml, flutter3.7

My Project was on flutter 2.5.3 and we decdied to upgrade code base to flutter latest version (3.7.3) . My version from pubspec.yaml used to be `1.2+10` after upgrading flutter. When I run `flutter pub get` or any other pub related command i am getting an error Invalid version number: Could not parse `1.2+10`.

Here is pubspec.yaml
[image]

Please help me fixing the issue. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

To quote from the documentation:

> A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
> followed by an optional build number separated by a +.

You only have two. So maybe change it to `1.2.0+10`

Comment: If I follow this convention it is showing different versions in android and ios.
in ios the version is 1.2.10
in android verison is 1.2.0.10
I want both of them to be same and in the format shown for ios (1.2.10)

Comment: @VelichetiSowmitri that doesn't sound right. `1.2.0+10` should translate to both platforms as `1.2.0`. If you want `1.2.10` you should use as version `1.2.10+X` where X is the version code for android. This is a number of your choice that should be increased on each publish of your app. I'm also surprised that accoring to you `1.2+10` worked at some point because I think that never should have worked. Maybe you just had `1.2.10` before

Comment: I used to use 1.2+10 and it worked for me from long back,(flutter v1 to v2.5) after upgrading to v3 It is not accepting the format

Comment: @VelichetiSowmitri ah okay, I didn't know that. I'm not sure then how to resolve your issue